# Typescript compute value of one property from another

Tags: typescript

In typescript we can create constant object like this:

```
export const AppConstants = {  
  VAL1: 'val1',
  VAL2: 'val2'
}
```

Question is, can we use one individual property from another inside one object (like below)?

```
export const AppConstants = {  
  VAL1: 'val1',
  VAL2: VAL1 + 'val2'
}
```

Comment: Is acceptable to define private variable to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a function to access the property:

```
export const AppConstants = {  
  VAL1: 'val1',
  VAL2: () => AppConstants.VAL1 + 'val2'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and then use it like a function AppConstants.VAL2()

Comment: In my case VAL2 was actually an array. 
export const AppConstants = {  
  VAL1: 'val1',
  VAL2: () => [AppConstants.VAL1 + 'val2']
}

So if I try AppConstants.VAL2, it wasn't working. AppConstants.VAL2 is working.

Comment: Yes sorry my bad :D I removed my comment

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to define a class. It will allow us to use `this` in a type-safe way. The second thing is `const assertion` this will ensure that values will be typed as literals, not just a `string`.

```js
class AppConstants {
  a = 'val1' as const  
  b = `${this.a}val2` as const
}

export const appConstants = new AppConstants();
let r1 = appConstants.a // 'val1'
let r2 = appConstants.b // 'val1val2'
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAO8DCB7AdhALmNmYG8AoaaMaAXmgHIA3MEARitJmHSxOOgCMLoADACT5MACwCWEAHRgAvnRAAmfi2hsMmQrMKEApgA94KAE6Y17M2ESoNOPHzS6A7nGsW7EABQBKANyEQXTNjBj4rZHdcaTIAehjqBSYAoOhjRTC3WyipXjiE%20gYFRSogA)

How `as const` works https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

How `template literals` works https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following

```js
const AppConstants = {  
  VAL1: 'val1',
}

AppConstants.VAL2 = AppConstants.VAL1 + 'val2';

console.log(AppConstants);
```